# Get mayor and last comment from foursquare page

Tags: foursquare

How can I get the last comment and who the mayor is from foursquare page ?

Let's say this is the url:

https://foursquare.com/v/anatomska-centrala/4dab1ba55da3ba8a479999b2.

And I need to fetch somehow this data:

**For last comment:**

Damir P. August 23, 2011
najjači fitness centar u gradu

**For mayor:**

Mayor: Mrgud N.
17 check-ins in last 60 days

I tried using foursquare's **Venue Detail** and combining it with the url's value (4dab1ba55da3ba8a479999b2) but unsuccessful.

I have non experience working with foursquare API so any help would be appreciate.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed retrieve the mayor and all tips ("comments") from the venue detail endpoint. Try this: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/4dab1ba55da3ba8a479999b2

In the response, look for `response.venue.mayor` and `response.venue.tips`.

Comment: That's just what I wanted. And you say that I fetch data [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/NezMH/)?

Comment: You shouldn't be making a call to developer.foursquare.com, your request should go directly to api.foursquare.com at the appropriate endpoint with parameters. You're also missing authentication. See: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#requests

Comment: I got it. Just one more question, [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/4dab1ba55da3ba8a479999b2) it says that the **OAuth token has been automatically added**. Will I have to change this token or can I use this one that has been automatically added ?

Comment: This is actually the OAuth token for *you*, the developer, so it's not recommended you use this. In your case, I would suggest making [userless requests](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#userless). I don't see any reason why you need auth so userless is probably the way to go; you'll also have a higher rate limit. Use the id/secret you get when you [create a new app](https://foursquare.com/developers/apps)